# Difference between map and map async

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have the following code

```
await Promise.all(
   products.map(async (product) => createProduct(product))
);
```

is there any functional need to use that `async` keyword? Because The logic works correctly without it.

Comment: What type does createProduct return?

Comment: It should be the same either way, so `async` is redundant. On the other hand it's not that big of a problem and it can be useful to mark that something is `async`. Doesn't seem to matter much, it's mostly down to preference, I'd say.

Comment: @zero298 a `Promise<any>`

Comment: Firstly, when running synchronously, you don't need Promise.all() nor do you need async keyword.

**async** keyword is mapping each item in the array to a promise. Hence the need for Promise.all() to wait for the result of these items.

To answer your question, functional need for async is to map every item to a promise and these items execute in parallel.